# Git unresponsive when used over VPN on Windows 7

Tags: windows, git, github, vpn, windows-server

This is regarding the unresponsiveness of simple git commands when working on local repositories over a VPN. My windows user account (admin role) is a domain account that I use to logon.

I have some local respositories that is cloned from a github origin.

Scenario 1: Working with Local Repository on windows without VPN.
Simple Commands like git-gui, git log etc work flawlessly.

Scenario 2: Working with the same local repo on widows WHILE CONNECTED to a vpn
The same simple commands dont work at all!! It takes forever to show an output. git log -2 takes 10 whole minutes vs 1 second without VPN.

My observation: When we execute git commands, other proceses like less.exe, ssh.exe are started which take a lot of time to respond. Is it because the system is trying to reach my windows domain for authentication which is unreachable from VPN network?

Any way to fix this?

Additional Data that might help:
I have services which are owned by my domain account. When connected via VPN, an attempt to start any of those services takes forever to start because it is tryign to reach my windows domain account for authentication which is unreachable via the VPN.

Comment: What git version are you using? Are you executing those command in a git bash or a CMD session?

Comment: @VonC I'm using the latest version of Git as of today. I'm running those in Git Bash. I also use it in Git Bash inside ConEmu

Comment: Does the issue persists if you try those commands in a simple CMD (or ConEmu CMD) session?

Comment: VPN's can just be really slow sometimes. Our work VPN is the worst. You might try using a different VPN service to see if quality improves.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Well, VPN works fine when i load websites and other things. But i dont get it...why is VPN involved when I am just working with local repositories and execuring simple commands like git gui or git log :??

Comment: @VonC Yes, it does...