# Git commands stalls when using over VPN

Tags: git, performance, cmd

When I connect to the VPN of my work, various git commands often stalls and becomes unresponsive for half a minute or so. Curiously, this is **only** affecting git commands from any command-line prompt; anything else network related has no issues. I have found [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38550893/2065863) but its not been answered for a long time.

- I run git commands in Windows `cmd` prompt, but same results with `GitBash`
- The remote server doesn't matter; any git repo (including github)
- **Only** git commands are affect when using the VPN
- Happens with any git commands, no specific ones, even `git branch` or `git log`

I set `GIT_TRACE=1` and `GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE=1` hoping this would help, here's an example trace:

```
D:\dev\myproject>git rebase --continue
13:22:49.431850 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin
13:22:49.432852 git.c:654               trace: exec: git-rebase --continue
13:22:49.433887 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: git-rebase --continue
13:23:32.623520 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
13:23:32.624518 trace.c:420             performance: 0.000009300 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' --exec-path
13:23:32.658520 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
13:23:32.658520 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --parseopt --stuck-long -- --continue
13:23:32.659522 trace.c:420             performance: 0.000609500 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' rev-parse --parseopt --stuck-long -- --continue
13:23:32.713552 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
13:23:32.714520 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --git-dir
13:23:32.715555 trace.c:420             performance: 0.001290900 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' rev-parse --git-dir
13:23:32.752519 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
13:23:32.753517 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --git-path objects
13:23:32.754564 trace.c:420             performance: 0.001305900 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' rev-parse --git-path objects
13:23:32.778544 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
13:23:32.779518 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --is-bare-repository
13:23:32.780524 trace.c:420             performance: 0.001338100 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' rev-parse --is-bare-repository
13:23:32.802548 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
13:23:32.802548 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --show-toplevel
13:23:32.803521 trace.c:420             performance: 0.001300100 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' rev-parse --show-toplevel
13:23:32.835520 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
13:23:32.836552 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git config --bool rebase.stat
13:23:32.836552 trace.c:420             performance: 0.001183800 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' config --bool rebase.stat
13:23:32.867519 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
13:23:32.869519 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git config --bool rebase.autostash
13:23:32.869519 trace.c:420             performance: 0.001215200 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' config --bool rebase.autostash
13:23:32.896553 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
13:23:32.897550 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git config --bool rebase.autosquash
13:23:32.897550 trace.c:420             performance: 0.001231500 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' config --bool rebase.autosquash
13:23:32.923525 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
13:23:32.924524 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git config --bool commit.gpgsign
13:23:32.924524 trace.c:420             performance: 0.001198700 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' config --bool commit.gpgsign
13:23:32.951553 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
13:23:32.952521 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --verify HEAD
13:23:32.953556 trace.c:420             performance: 0.001634100 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' rev-parse --verify HEAD
13:23:32.978524 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
13:23:32.980524 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git update-index --ignore-submodules --refresh
13:23:32.982520 read-cache.c:1914       performance: 0.000848500 s: read cache .git/index
13:23:32.993522 preload-index.c:111     performance: 0.010783200 s: preload index
13:23:32.994521 read-cache.c:1472       performance: 0.000086300 s: refresh index
13:23:32.994521 trace.c:420             performance: 0.015293500 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' update-index --ignore-submodules --refresh
13:23:33.015519 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
13:23:33.017524 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules
13:23:33.019521 read-cache.c:1914       performance: 0.000876900 s: read cache .git/index
13:23:33.028525 preload-index.c:111     performance: 0.009241400 s: preload index
13:23:33.029520 diff-lib.c:250          performance: 0.000109500 s: diff-files
13:23:33.029520 trace.c:420             performance: 0.013211400 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules
13:23:33.117520 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
13:23:33.117520 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git hash-object -t tree nul
13:23:33.119560 trace.c:420             performance: 0.001288800 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' hash-object -t tree nul
13:23:33.167521 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
13:23:33.169522 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git rebase--helper --continue
13:23:33.171555 read-cache.c:1914       performance: 0.000881700 s: read cache .git/index
13:23:33.181524 preload-index.c:111     performance: 0.010163900 s: preload index
13:23:33.182520 read-cache.c:1472       performance: 0.000064800 s: refresh index
13:23:33.191549 diff-lib.c:250          performance: 0.000105800 s: diff-files
13:23:33.194520 diff-lib.c:527          performance: 0.003154300 s: diff-index
13:23:33.201519 preload-index.c:111     performance: 0.001590700 s: preload index
13:23:33.201519 read-cache.c:1472       performance: 0.000038800 s: refresh index
13:23:33.206524 diff-lib.c:527          performance: 0.000433400 s: diff-index
13:23:33.210556 read-cache.c:1914       performance: 0.000717400 s: read cache .git/index
13:23:33.229556 read-cache.c:2411       performance: 0.002439200 s: write index, changed mask = a
13:23:33.287555 diff-lib.c:527          performance: 0.000508200 s: diff-index
13:23:33.290520 read-cache.c:1914       performance: 0.001063000 s: read cache .git/index
13:23:33.320554 read-cache.c:2411       performance: 0.003530800 s: write index, changed mask = a
13:23:33.417522 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: git notes copy --for-rewrite=rebase
13:23:33.427523 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
13:23:33.429524 git.c:415               trace: built-in: git notes copy --for-rewrite=rebase
13:23:33.431521 trace.c:420             performance: 0.003135300 s: git command: git notes copy --for-rewrite=rebase
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/test/foo.
13:23:33.440524 trace.c:420             performance: 0.272667800 s: git command: 'C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git.exe' rebase--helper --continue
13:23:33.449522 trace.c:420             performance: 44.017249600 s: git command: git.exe rebase --continue
```

Something is going on between

```
13:22:49.433887 run-command.c:637       trace: run_command: git-rebase --continue
```

and

```
13:23:32.623520 exec-cmd.c:236          trace: resolved executable dir: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
```

its taking ~43 seconds just for that step. Is there any way to get even more data to see what is going there? This issue has been driving me crazy, and IT is just unable to figure out the exact cause. Anyone else experienced this before?

Thanks!

Comment: The issue was resolved when IT decided to change the VPN application. I guess this could have been resolved by changing something on the VPN configuration either server or client side, but unfortunately I don't know what it could have been.